# CSS: Wrapper div collapsing when positioning children. Is there a better way?

Tags: css, button, positioning

I'm trying to solve OK/CANCEL button placement for our internal app's.
We want the OK and Cancel buttons to be consistently placed (and styled).

My thought was simply to drop our buttons in a button-wrapper, and then position them in relationship to that wrapper.

The problem comes in, though, with how the wrapper collapses to 0 height when I the button are plucked with `position: absolute;`.
Because of this collapsed div, my buttons end up dangling.

Example:

```
/*** css ***/
section.blah{
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1.5em 1em;
}
.button-wrapper{ 
    position:relative;
}
.button-wrapper .proceed{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
.button-wrapper .cancel{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}

/*** html ***/
<section class="blah">
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button class="btn proceed">OK</button>
        <button class="btn cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

As you can see, we simply want the "OK" type buttons to be on one side, and the "Cancel" type buttons to be on the other. 
Is `position:absolute;` the best way to do this?
If so, what would be an elegant way to ensure that my buttons don't dangle over other objects?

(NOTE: I *thought* about just assigning a fixed height to the wrapper, but that seems entirely too in-flexible. The solution needs to allow buttons of any size.)

Comment: **OMG** _!!!_ I can't believe I didn't think of using TWO floats! Hehe, I thought of floating right OR left, but not both :) _** THANKS A BUNCH FOR ALL THE QUICK ANSWERS**_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute` is not really meant for this purpose.

All you really need here is a `float:left` on .cancel and `float:right` on .proceed

Once you do this, however, you will still have the same issue of the height being 0 on .button-wrapper.  This is where `clear:both` comes in.

You will need a `clear:both` after the two floated elements.  You can add it in one of two ways:

1)  Add a new div after .proceed and .cancel: `<div class="clear"></div>` with the following css:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

2) You can use the :after pseudo selector on .button-wrapper, to add the clear with CSS only:

```
.button-wrapper:after {

  content: '.';
  display: block;
  clear:both;
  visibility:hidden;
  height:0;

}
```

EDIT:  Here is a JSFiddle illustrating option 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/P5gj4/

Comment: So far there are THREE correct answers. I'm selecting this one because it is the best balance of completeness and quickness in response. Thanks-a-bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use floats. You need to "clear" block that wrap floats, for example use `overflow:hidden`. There are lot of articles about floats and clearing you can read.

http://jsfiddle.net/89NUZ/

```
.button-wrapper{ 
    overflow:hidden;
}
.button-wrapper .proceed{
    float:left;
}
.button-wrapper .cancel{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am blushing a little from having missed this myself. Your response in much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to position them with floats instead of using the the position property.

Something like this maybe:

```
section.blah {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1.5em 1em;
}
.button-wrapper{ 
   overflow: hidden;
}
.button-wrapper .proceed{
   float: right;
}
.button-wrapper .cancel{
   float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4CpaW/

I've set overflow to hidden on the parent to clear the floats.